# printing mysql database to a html page in socket.io and node.js

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to be able to print mysql data to a html page just to test it so i can start learning

**Upadated Code**

**here is what i have tried on my server.js**

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('testsql.html');
  //res.sendfile('/login/');
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "users"
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('a client connected');

    con.query('SELECT * FROM users',function(err,rows){
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
      console.log(rows);
      socket.emit('showrows', rows);
    });



});
```

**And Here is My Client Code **

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing socket.io</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="socketio"> not connected </h1>
    <div id="display"> </div>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('connect', function() {
        document.getElementById("socketio").innerHTML = "socket connected";
      });
      socket.on('showrows', function(dbData) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = dbData;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the client is showing that it is connecting to the server but it is not displaying the query result on the client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following changes:

in the server:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "users"
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('a client connected');

    con.query('SELECT * FROM users',function(err,rows){
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
      console.log(rows);
      socket.emit('showrows', rows);
    });



 });
```

in the client:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing socket.io</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="socketio"> not connected </h1>
    <div id="display"> </div>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('connect', function() {
        document.getElementById("socketio").innerHTML = "socket connected";
      });
      socket.on('showrows', function(rows) {
        var html='';
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
          html += rows[i].firstname + ' ' + rows[i].lastname + '<br>';
        }  
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = html;
        console.log(rows);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this at least shows the whole table in the console just not on the client html page

Comment: I don't see jquery nor socket.io loaded into your client code

Comment: I edited my answer and added some lines to your client.html for a good start

Comment: Sir thanks for all the hard work you are doing to help me it shows that the client is connecting to the server and everytime i refresh it displays the database in the console just not on the client [here](http://billischill.ddns.net:3000) is the page the test is on if you want to see for yourself

Comment: Ok, let's change one line in the server: `socket.emit('showrows', dbData);` to the following: `socket.emit('showrows', 'These are some rows:<br>first row<br>second row<br>third row');`

Comment: it shows those so that part is working now we just need to make it emit a variable that stores the query ?? maybe

Comment: yes, our client is ok but the server is not, please show the whole code of the `server.js`

Comment: I edited the server code once again, can you please try it?

Comment: I used your new code for the server and this is what the client says [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: I updated my code again with your latest update is it looking like its supposed too?

Comment: no, it is not looking good - I can't see the rows with data. Please add one line to the client, just below the line: `document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = rows;` add `console.log(rows);`

Comment: My pleasure :) Now going to bed, it's 4am here ;)

Comment: now i just need to figure out how to make a login system and display there name when they are logged in thank you soooo much

Answer (score 0):

I see the following typo: `socket.brodcast.emit('showrows', rows);` which should be `socket.broadcast.emit('showrows', rows);`

But in your case, you only need `socket.emit('showrows', rows)`. And in order to listen to this on the client side, you need to have this:

```
socket.on('showrows', function(rows){
    console.log(rows);
    jQuery("#display").append(rows);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are trying to create a connection to mysql server twice.

And I believe there is something that you missed out for your client side.You forgot to connect to your socket.io server.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {'reconnect': true, 'force new connection': true, 'connect timeout': 1000});

socket.on('showrows', function(rows) {
    jQuery("#display").append(rows);
});
```

You should also make sure your client is connected to the server before emitting your query result.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

   //Run your mysql query method

  //Socket disconnected
    socket.once('disconnect', function () {

    });
});
```

Update: Only end the mysql connection when you are done querying.

```
con.connect(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log('Error connecting to Db');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connection established');
});

//Don't recreate a mysql connection


con.query('SELECT * FROM users',function(err,rows){
  if(err) throw err;

  console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
  console.log(rows);
});


con.end(function(err) {
  // The connection is terminated gracefully
  // Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
  // before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
});
```

Comment: There is still nothing showing up exept for the it works paragraph

Comment: Maybe you can try updating your code above so that we know what you did.

Comment: @NicholasHendricks I have updated my code. Check out the last part.

Comment: I have updated my code am i headed in the right direction?

Comment: @NicholasHendricks you need to include jQuery and socket.io client script in your html code. For server side, you can create connection to your mysql server before any client connect to the server. You'll only have to query if there is user connected to your server and only emit to your client when there is result return from mysql query.

Comment: I am really sorry guys but all of these methods are not seeming to work I think i have the code mixed up and placed not where it is supposed to be could you please help me out